# Como criar um filtro de pesquisa para tabela html?

Tags: javascript, html

Como faço para criar uma pesquisa aproximada em uma tabela com paginação?
A pesquisa que eu estava usando não filtrava os dados da outra página, apenas o da página atual.
Preciso de um código que faça isso, por favor.

**Função JS**
[image: A função JS]
**Tabela**
[image: Tabela]

Comment: Os dados estão em um array?

Comment: Pra fazer isso vc teria que fazer uma busca global na fonte dos dados, já que não tem como acessar via JavaScript o HTML das outras páginas sem consultar o servidor.

Answer (score -1):

Vocẽ pode dar uma olhada em DataTables, segue o link:

https://datatables.net/

Já utilizei e me ajudou bastante!

Comment: Realmente, é algo muito bom, porém eu queria a função JS só pra complementar na tabela e na lógica que eu ja tenho. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Você consegue colocar a lógica na pergunta? Para eu dar uma olhada. Valeu! @GuilhermeHenrique